# allowing python to impoert csv with duplicate column names in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, duplicates, multiple-columns

i have a data frame that looks like this:
[image]

there are in  total 109 columns.
when i import the data using the read_csv it adds ".1",".2" to duplicate names .
is there any way to go around  it ?

i have tried this :

```
  df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\agns1\Downloads\treatment1.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1", 
  sep='|', header=None)

  df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], copy=False).iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

but it changed the data frame and wasnt helpful.
this is what it did to my data
python:

[image]

excel:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `header=None`, because it is used for avoid convert first row of file to `df.columns` and then remove `.` with digits from columns names:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\agns1\Downloads\treatment1.csv',encoding="ISO-8859-1", sep=',')

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\.\d+$','')
```

Comment: it still changes the data like in the picture above

Comment: @ElizaR - Can you explain more? What means change data? Are not floats? Or are strings?

Comment: when i open it again in excel as csv ot looks like it made it into lists seperated by commas

Comment: there is a picture above how it looks

Comment: @ElizaR - but it is expected, because excel open file csv with coma like it.

Comment: the thing is how can i make python not write the ".1" at the duplicate name  and get back a data frame whith columns and rows and not as lisits

Comment: @ElizaR - `the thing is how can i make python not write the ".1" at the duplicate name` - now in pandas not supported, ` data frame whith columns and rows and not as lisits` what is `print (df.head().to_dict())` after `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\.\d+$','')` ?

Comment: 'None.Other.Other.Other.Other.Other,Actinomycetaceae,Bifidobacteriaceae,Coriobacteriaceae,Coriobacteriaceae  and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239772/discussion-between-eliza-r-and-jezrael).

Comment: i aded a picture what it did to the data it made it into lists rather then looking like table

Comment: @ElizaR - is in inoput data separator `|` ? or `,` ?

Comment: the data is with seperator  :"|" aftr using:f.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\.\d+$','')

Comment: @ElizaR - how working if change `sep='|')` to `sep=',')` ?

Comment: sorry to ask again :) i just tried mergin the columns with the same name together with :df.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum() to have one long colimn with same name instead X columns with the same name ( but different observations ) didnt do anythong at all ? is there any other way?

Comment: @ElizaR - It join values instead `sum` ? If yes, what is `print (df.dtypes)` ?

Comment: it is float64 and int64  , but it didnt creat the long columns the data stayed as it was

Comment: @ElizaR - tested with `df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=["a", "a", "c"])` and your solution working well.

Comment: using your example what i wanted to create id a table that looks like this : a   c                                                                                                                                                            
    1    5                                                                                                                                                                                                             
   2      6                 
   4                                                           
    5

Comment: so a would be along column containing the numbers 1,2,4,5 and c column 3,6

Comment: @ElizaR - Can you try `df.astype(str).groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).apply(lambda x: ','.join(np.ravel(x))).reset_index(name='val')` ?

Comment: yes still didnt get the lonng column the data stayed as it was